# Appending and styling label and span inside a div correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What am I doing wrong in this fiddle? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/1345/)

What I am trying to accomplish is have multiple divs inside another div that have labels and spans inside of them. label has to be on the left and span with text on the right with a solid border on the bottom of each div to separate them.

In the fiddle above, I can't even set the background to a color for the div. Something like this:

```
<div class="standards">
     <div class=""><label></label><span><span></div>
     <div class=""><label></label><span><span></div>
     <div class=""><label></label><span><span></div>
</div>
```

so eventually result should look like

```
HTO    some text
__________________

HTO    some text
__________________
```

Comment: Look in to "css clearfix" and add `overflow: auto;` to `.tab_field_pair` for the background to appear.

Comment: Ok.. I was able to get it working correctly this way  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/1348/)

Comment: I have updated the fiddle for anyone in the future. http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/1350/

Answer (score 0):

$('.tab_field_pair') selects all html nodes that have the corresponding class. So when you appended the first one and want to append the 2nd one, it would select both div's.

Here is what you can do:

```
var code = "HT0";
var label = 'evaluate the social, political, economic, and cultural contributions of individuals and groups from various societies, past and present'

var length = 5;

for (var i = 0; i <= length; i++){
var $div=$("<div class='tab_field_pair'> </div>");
$('.standards').append($div);
$div.append("<label id='standardscode'>" + code + "</label><span id='standardslabel'>" + label + "</span>")
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/1351/

Comment: By the way, you are having ONE div having the class of "standards". If you had more, it would append it to all html tags having this class.